# Calculate Average For Specific Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following columns:

```
Brand   Reviews Rating
Test    25  4.5
Test    26  3.5
Test    41  4.3
Test2   20  2.1
Test2   15  4
Test3   29  5
Test3   22  3.3
```

[image: table]

I would like to calculate the total amount of reviews just for the brand TEST. How can I proceed?

Comment: I would think that a simple SUMIF() would suffice:  `=SUMIF(A:A,"Test",B:B)`

Comment: It actually works! Any trick in case I would need also a =counta ? (I need it :P )

Comment: do you mean COUNTIF:  `=COUNTIF(A:A,"Test")`?

Comment: @ScottCraner I do have columns with text (some without) and I would just need to count how many rows have text, for which brand which is why I want to do a COUNTA as COUNTIF doesn't work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"Test", B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIF(A:A,"Test",B:B) thanks to @ScottCraner